# Get запросы в express js

Tags: express

Есть маршрут:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

На него приходят параметры типа:

```
?name=dima&age=27
```

Как не зная имен этих параметров прочесть их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно внутри функции перебрать `res.query` - простой массив типа ключ-значение, в котором собственно и хранятся параметры запроса.

Comment: В js нет массивов "ключ-значеие" (ассоциативные массивы). Там есть только объекты.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в абсолютном большинстве случаев реализованные именно как ассоциативные массивы ) Строго говоря, в до ES6 и честного OOP то в языке не было - одни условности только.

Comment: ООП там как раз было и довольно мощное. Просто не все умеют работать с наследованием на основе прототипов ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не было. Прототипы - это лишь сторонний костыль, используемый из-за отсутствия ООП в самом языке. И да, ООП - это далеко не только возможность наследования.

Comment: ООП - это наследование, инкапсуляция и полиморфизм? а чего из этого нет в JS?) И прототипы - это не костыль. Это просто другой подход к наследованию. В ES6 объектная модель в JS **не меняется**. Совсем. Все, что есть нового в ES6 по классам -- это синтаксический сахар.